# rails uniqueness of two fields combination

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with field a, b. I want to make sure that the combination of a and b is unique in the table, so a=1, b=2 and a=2, b=1 would raise a conflict.

I have try `validates_uniqueness_of :a, :scope => :b`, but it only make sure that no two
a=1, b=2 row can exist, I also want to filter out the a=2, b=1.  Thanks

Comment: It makes sense that this is not supported out of the box I'd say. You should just build your own validation method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in uniqueness validator does not support that, as far as I know. You would have to write a custom validation for that, e.g.:

```
class MyModel < AR::Base

  validate :my_custom_validation

  def my_custom_validation
    if self.class.where("(a = :a AND b = :b) OR (a = :b AND b = :a)", {:a => a, :b => b}).exists?
      errors.add(:a, :taken)
    end
  end
end
```

This will add a validation error to attribute `a` if there is any record having (a = 1 AND b = 2) OR (a = 2 AND b = 1).

Answer (score 0):

Might want to have a look at
http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/

Comment: There's no mention of `a` and `b` being the primary key, so one could just declare a UNIQUE key constraint to keep this validation in the database side. Also, this would still work just like the built-in validation, not they way yngum wants. It would still allow two rows where one has a=1, b=2 and the other a=2, b=1